# Is there a program that calculates values from the recurrence relation or from combinatorial definition?

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to make a table of values of (for example) Stirling numbers of the second kind. Is there any program that calculates those values from the reucurrence relation or combinatorial definition?

Stirling number of the second kind `S(n,k)` is the number of ways to partition a set of n objects into k non-empty subsets.

The recurrence relation: `S(n,k) = S(n-1, k-1) + k S(n-1, k)`.

Thank you.

Comment: How efficient would it need to be? This is an almost elementary application of recursive programming and a naive implementation can be done pretty easily in most programming languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While one could just implement such a method naively, using the recursive definition (actual python code below)

```py
def S(n,k):
    if n == k or k == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return S(n-1, k-1) + k*S(n-1, k)

def print_table(limit):
    for n in range(1,limit):
        for k in range(1,n+1):
            print(S(n,k), end=' ')
        print()

print_table(11)
```

which outputs

```
1 
1 1 
1 3 1 
1 7 6 1 
1 15 25 10 1 
1 31 90 65 15 1 
1 63 301 350 140 21 1 
1 127 966 1701 1050 266 28 1 
1 255 3025 7770 6951 2646 462 36 1 
1 511 9330 34105 42525 22827 5880 750 45 1
```

in a fraction of second.

For much larger values you'll want to tackle this differently, as you would hit recursion limits or hit a stack overflow, not to mention the exponential increase in number of function calls.
Is n and k < 10 and you only need to call this once and just experiment with recurrence relations, just go ahead and use the script above.

---

A technique used to tackle larger values for `n` and `k` can be to use [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) on inherently recursive problems (or just because it is convenient).

Memoization is basically like constructing the table of values that you actually request here, so we can just construct that directly:

```py
x = 100
s2 = [[0]*(i+1) for i in range(x)]
# boundary conditions, n == k or k == 1 -> 1:
for n in range(x):
    s2[n][n] = 1

for n in range(2,x):
    s2[n][2] = 1

for n in range(2,x):
    for k in range(2,n):
        s2[n][k] = s2[n-1][k-1] + k*s2[n-1][k]  # uses memory from earlier in the loop.

print(s2[99][28])
```

takes only a fraction of a second to run and prints the very large (and what I hope is the correct):

```
259777504831056559420676527271646094360016421009000678651645126828200235188209536387490703366601715430858018913780
```

Disclaimer: You could definitely vectorize this with `numpy`, but be aware that the limiting factor here is not really performance, but storage for the extremely large integer types needed; not a good fit for `numpy` as they are far beyond `int64` (and quickly outgrow even `float64`).